# Access the compilation date during compilation in Haxe

Tags: macros, haxe

I was wondering whether it is possible to access external information - like the current date during compilation.

It would then be possible to do something like this:

```
class MyInfo {
    private var buildDate:Int = --- AUTOMATICALLY INSERT THE CURRENT UNIX DATE TIME HERE ---;

    public function getInfo():String { // example usage
        return "This library was compiled the " + buildDate;
    }
}
```

I thought about accessing this information in the compilation bat/sh/make file and then pass it to the compiler, too. (Something similar to "-D".) However the Haxe compiler does not seem to support an argument like:

```
haxe --main MyInfo --js test.js -SOMEARG date=$(date)
```

So that I could use the content of the variable date afterwards ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be done with macros (code executing at compile-time).

Your date example is covered in the cookbook, [here](https://code.haxe.org/category/macros/generating-code-in-a-macro.html).
You can find more about macros [in the haxe manual](https://haxe.org/manual/macro.html) or in the [cookbook](https://code.haxe.org/category/macros/).

Edit: 
Minimal example:

```
class Test {
  public static function main() {
    trace(getBuildTime());
  }

  public static macro function getBuildTime() {
    var buildTime = Math.floor(Date.now().getTime() / 1000);

    return macro $v{buildTime};
  }
}
```

The time will be computed at compile-time.